# Trying to figure out what this haskell code means

Tags: haskell, programming-languages

Hey I'm very new to haskell and I can't quite seem to understand what is going on in this chunk of code

```
execCBN :: Program -> Exp
execCBN (Prog e) = evalCBN e

evalCBN :: Exp -> Exp
evalCBN (EApp e1 e2) = case (evalCBN e1) of
    (EAbs i e1') -> evalCBN (subst i e2 e1')
    e1' -> EApp e1' e2
evalCBN (EIf e1 e2 e3 e4) = if (evalCBN e1) == (evalCBN e2) then evalCBN e3 else evalCBN e4
evalCBN (ELet i e1 e2) = evalCBN (EApp (EAbs i e2) e1) 
evalCBN (ERec i e1 e2) = evalCBN (EApp (EAbs i e2) (EFix (EAbs i e1))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand Haskell code, you usually want to look first at the types!  You haven't included them here, but they probably look something like this:

```
newtype Program = Program Exp

data Exp
    = EApp Exp Exp
    | EAbs String Exp
    | EIf Exp Exp Exp Exp
    | ELet String Exp Exp
    | ERec String Exp Exp
    | EFix Exp
    | EVar String
```

I'm guessing at some details of the `Exp` type, for sure!

Now, here's what's going on.  This defines the abstract syntax tree for a very simple programming language based on lambda calculus.  Each of the constructors for `Exp` is some syntax construct in the language: an function application (`EApp`), a lambda (`EAbs`), an if statement (`EIf`), and so on.  The `evalCBN` function is defining an interpreter, or evaluator, for that programming language.  Because there are many different syntax constructs, `evalCBN` is defined with *pattern matching*, where there's a different equation for each kind of syntax node that might need to be evaluated.  Because the tree structure is recursive, the evaluation function is also recursive.

Presumably, the name `evalCBN` refers to the fact that it's evaluating using a "call by need" strategy, as opposed to a "call by value" strategy.  You can see that in the equation for applying a function:

```
evalCBN (EApp e1 e2) = case (evalCBN e1) of
    (EAbs i e1') -> evalCBN (subst i e2 e1')
    e1' -> EApp e1' e2
```

Notice how the argument `e2` isn't evaluated at all.  Instead, it's just substituted in its unevaluated form into the expression `e1'`.  A call by value variation would evaluate `e2` before substituting it.

The equations for `ELet` and `ERec` (non-recursive let, and recursive let) are interesting in that all they do is rewrite the `ELet` or `ERec` into a different expression, and evaluate that instead.  This is a great example of what's called "syntactic sugar".  These syntactic forms don't make the language any more expressive; instead, they get shallowly rewritten into more a fundamental form in a "desugaring" process.

If you have further questions, please ask something more specific.  There's a lot to this bit of code, so I can't answer everything!

Comment: Is there any way you can help with another part of this?